# how to refresh parent aspx page from popup window without security prompt

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am opening a popup window using showModalDialog and refreshing the parent page on popup close is working, however it also gives me the "internet explorer needs to resend the information" prompt which is totally unwanted, how can I get rid of this.

PS. I cannot use Ajax here.

thanks.

Comment: Just for clarification, "internet explorer needs to resend the information" isn't a security prompt, it's just letting you know that there could be unexpected side effects from reloading the page since the post data used to load the current page will be sent again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "refreshing the parent page", do you mean simply reloading the page from the server?

If it is a simple GET, you should be able to use `location.reload(true)`.

If you need something more complex, you'll need to provide a bit more detail.

**EDIT:**

Based on the code in your comments, it appears that you are reloading the parent window location in several different ways, which seems unnecessary at best. Also, if you reached the current page via a POST (in ASP.Net, generally a "Postback"), then calling location.reload() actually triggers the POST to be resent. It is the resend of the POST that is causing the prompt, where IE wants you to know that you're about to perform a duplicate submission of data to the server (in case that might cause issues).

When you "refresh" the page, can it be a clean request to the parent page, or does it need to resubmit prior data? If the request can be a GET, try removing the "doOnClose" method of the popup page and allow "window.location = window.location" in the parent page to reload the page.

Comment: btnNotes.Attributes.Add("onClick", "window.showModalDialog('" & urlPath & "', window, 'center:yes;resizable:no;dialogHeight:300px'); window.location = window.location;")

Comment: the above code calls the popup window. then the popup window has code: function doOnLoad() { xWin = window.dialogArguments; } function doOnClose() { xWin.location.href = unescape(xWin.location.pathname); xWin.location.reload(); xWin.location.replace(xWin.location); ... this reloads the parent but also gives me the security prompt.     sorry I don't have the edit toolbar (it's missing to format the code...

Comment: yes, it can be a clean request to the parent page as the child page does the data manipulation, then a clean request should present the new data? but after I removed the "doOnClose" of the child page, when the child closes the parent page does not display the new data in the grid.

Comment: actually it looks like it is not even hitting the window.location = window.location; part. I replaced it with: window.location = 'http://localhost/SiteSelection/dummypage.aspx' a page that does not even exist and when the clild closes IE does not even complain, just goes back to the same (unchanged but should display new data) original parent page.

Comment: now I added the following in place of the window.location = window.location on the page page to link to an existing page1.aspx, the alert part happens but it then goes back to the original parent page not page1.aspx: alert('hello'); window.location = 'http://localhost/SiteSelection/page1.aspx'

Comment: thought I'd try another way around and just use javascript to update the particular control in the parernt form grid that is being edited by the popup by returning the new value from the popup then setting the control value to this new value, but for some reason the page is still posting back...

Comment: final deal: I am using javascript and doing all the updating of the parnet page on the client, less traffic anyway. When the child window closes I am passing back the edited value to the parent via window.returnValue = "editedvalue"  then updating the parent page control with the new value using document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "editedvalue";  ( I get the id of the control in the grid's GridView1_RowDataBound method and add the call to the parent's javascript function in the grid button's onclick after the call to open the child window. Thanks for all the help everyone.